# Jquery ui drag drop droppable "drop" event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

When I make a div `droppable` and try to set a `drop` event function it doesn't fire:

```
$('.item').draggable({

});

$('.destination').droppable({
   drop: function(event, ui){
     console.log('hiii');
   }
});
```

It fires when I drop it outside- to the right of the $('.destination') div, but not if I drop it inside the '.destination' div.
See the full JS fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/dylanjha/8TFMS/5/

Comment: It's working fine for me. I'm using Firefox.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For some reason, setting the `margin:0 auto` on the `.item` class causes this to not function properly. Removing it fixes the issue.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8TFMS/6/)**